# upload file to box api v2 using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, box-api

I'm trying to upload file to box using v2. The only result i get is the error while uploading. I'm able to authenticate, get the auth token but not able to upload, I have given the code which i'm using. If i'm wrong anyway just correct me. Any help will be appreciated!!

```
    public function upload(argFile:flash.filesystem.File):void{ 

        argFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
            function onComplete(event:Event):void
            {
                trace("complete:"+event.toString());
            }
        ); 
        argFile.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,
            function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace("Error:"+event.toString());
            }
        ); 


        var url:String = "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/data";  

        // Setup the custom header 
        var customHeader:String = "BoxAuth api_key=" + api_key + "&auth_token=" + auth_token;
        var headers:Array = [ 
            new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", customHeader) 
        ]; 

        // create the url-vars 
        var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
        urlVars.filename1 = '@'+argFile.name; 
        urlVars.folder_id = "0"; 

        // create the url-reqeust 
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(); 
        request.contentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

        // set ther url 
        request.url = url; 

        // set the header 
        request.requestHeaders = headers; 

        // set the vars 
        request.data = urlVars; 
        try { 
            argFile.upload(request); 
        } catch (e:Error) 
        { 
            trace(e.toString(), "Error (catch all)"); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: The above code is working fine! i forgot to check if the file exists!!